# how to redirecting from subdomain to main domain by mvc routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have a controller in my sub domain  and from this controller i want to redirect user to main domain but i use  response code but it will not works how can i use redirect to action?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Redirect("maindomain.com");
        return View();
    }
```

in this code when you set a break point on return View(); line response not works and breadline goes to next line.

i want user redirecting to this

```
  url : http://www.maindomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the redirect ensure the code stops executing.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("www.maindomain.com");
    }
```